# How to Center Custom Wordpress Theme Navigation bar?

Tags: css, wordpress, header, nav, navigationbar

Hello Fellow Programmers

I would like to center the navigation and have researched and don't know the code to insert to my custom made theme which I converted from HTML to Wordpress. (I'm a little new to Wordpress Theme Development)

My Custom-made wordpress theme already pulls whatever menu is on wordpress and inserts it in.

But I just need help centering the menu. observe the picture below... The menu is too far to the left.

Here is some relevant code I have currently on the website in my "header.php" which displays the WordPress menu.

(Header.php File)

`<nav class="menubar">
    <ul id="menu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu();?>
    </nav>`

[Image of my navigation menu which appears more on the left side.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuslC.png)

P.S. Please help me with simply centering my menu, your response(s) is(are) most appreciated.

Comment: What you use to output the menu has little to no importance in writing the CSS for centering it. Please provide a [mcve] making sure the problem is reproduced. You are also required to research and have at least one attempt at coding this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menubar, #menu {
    width:100%;
}

#menu {
    text-alighn:center;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could also wrap the navbar in a wrapper div and give it the same width as the main content of the site(this may or may not be what you're looking for).

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
<nav class="menubar">
    <ul id="menu">
    <?php wp_nav_menu();?>
    </nav></div>

.nav-wrapper{
max-width: 1170px; /* let's say this is the width of the main div */
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```